# How to store a list of objects in application settings

Tags: c#, application-settings

I have recently became familiar with C# application settings, and it seems cool.
I was searching for a way to store a list of custom objects, but I couldn't find a way!
Actually I saw a [post to store int[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766610/how-to-store-int-array-in-application-settings), but it wasn't helpful for this problem.
I tried to change the config of that solution in order to make it suitable for my problem. the XML config file of that was:

```
<Setting Name="SomeTestSetting" Type="System.Int32[]" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)" />
</Setting>
```

I tried to address my object as quoted below in the type attribute but it wasn't helpful since it doesn't recognizing my object... I tried "type = List" and "type="tuple[]"
both of these options didn't help me!

I have a class looks like:

```
class tuple
    {
        public tuple()
        {
            this.font = new Font ("Microsoft Sans Serif",8);
            this.backgroundcolor_color = Color.White;
            this.foregroundcolor_color = Color.Black;
        }
        public string log { get; set; }
        public Font font { get ; set; }
        public String fontName { get; set; }
        public string foregroundcolor { get; set; }
        public Color foregroundcolor_color { get; set; }
        public string backgroundcolor { get; set; }
        public Color backgroundcolor_color { get; set; }
        public Boolean notification { get; set; }
    }
```

and I want to store a list in application setting.
So is there any way to achieve this purpose.
Thanks in advance.
Cheers,

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627887/store-a-range-of-values-in-web-config-what-data-structure-to-use/8627974#8627974

Comment: take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922047/store-dictionarystring-string-in-application-settings it might be helps you...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) to serialize list of tuples as byte array and Base64 (as quite efficient way) to store byte array as `string`.

First of all change your class to something like that (hint: [`[SerializableAttribute]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx)):

```
[Serializable()]
public class tuple
{
    public tuple()
    {
        this.font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8);
    //....
}
```

Add property in settings named `tuples` and type of `string`.

[image: tuples in Settings]

Then you can use two methods to load and save generic list of tuples (`List<tuple>`):

```
void SaveTuples(List<tuple> tuples)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(ms, tuples);
        ms.Position = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)ms.Length];
        ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Properties.Settings.Default.tuples = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}

List<tuple> LoadTuples()
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(Properties.Settings.Default.tuples)))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        return (List<tuple>)bf.Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
List<tuple> list = new List<tuple>();
list.Add(new tuple());
list.Add(new tuple());
list.Add(new tuple());
list.Add(new tuple());
list.Add(new tuple());

// save list
SaveTuples(list);

// load list
list = LoadTuples();
```

I leave `null`, empty string and exception checking up to you.

Comment: I wonder why this get downvote, it would be nice to know what is wrong.

Comment: I don't think **sr** (`StreamReader`) in the `SaveTuples` method serves any purpose, so the second using statement can be safely removed.

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 3):

Application configuration is not the good choice for *storing* the data at application runtime. 
For this use any available in `.NET` serialization option like

- [Xml Serialization](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization)
- Binary serialization with [proto-buf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)
- [Json serialization](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx)
- ORM mapping to some embedde database [Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

and many others...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're wanting to do is best done in application settings. What you might want to look into is XDocument, and storing the values you need in a seperate configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for your time and consideration could you pleases give me some hints about XDocument and what it is? and what did you mean by storing the values in a seperate config file?

Comment: XDocument is one of the classes for manipulating xml files within .NET. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx If you're actually looking to store the entire stucture, XML serialization might be your better bet though.

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom types to extend `.config` files. But this will not be storing your own arbitrary types in an existing section of confirmation but adding custom sections.

A custom configuration type could, by providing completely custom logic for child nodes, hold XML serialised data. I would argue that this is abusing the configuration system: it is for storing settings not complete state.

If this is what you want, there is a simple example in the documentation for [`ConfigurationSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for you response, but do you have any suggestion for achieving this purpose? to save this object and retrieve it later?

Comment: @Ehsan Define a custom class based on `ConfigurationSection` with the right set of properties. Use `ConfigurationManager` to load config (including user levels) and, later, save.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr.Tigran mentioned You can simply use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json#) Nuget Package to convert your Object(which can be a List or contain a List) using serialization and save it as a string (I made a string variable in Settings with "User Scope" and named it "myString"):

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
Properties.Settings.Default.myString = json;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

To load it we use deserialization :

```
string json = Properties.Settings.Default.myString;
myObject myobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myObject>(json);
```