# How can I store List<T> in local settings?

Tags: c#, .net, list, windows-phone-8.1

Currently i am using the following method to store the data which compiles successfully

```
App.removalList.Add(new RemoveFavourites(App.user.auth_token, App.user.user_id, proid.ToString()));

ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["Remove_fav_properties_list"] = App.removalList;
```

It compiles successfully however i am getting the following error at runtime:

> **WinRT information: Error trying to serialize the value to be written to the application data store.**
>   **Additional information: Data of this type is not supported.**

Following is the RemoveFavourites Class:

```
public class RemoveFavourites
{

    public string auth_token { get; set; }

    public string user_id { get; set; }

    public string property_id { get; set; }

    public RemoveFavourites(string auth_token, string user_id, string property_id)
    {
        this.auth_token = auth_token;
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.property_id = property_id;
    }
}
```

and the complete exception is

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>   WinRT information: Error trying to serialize the value to be written to the application data store
>   Additional information: Data of this type is not supported.
>   Error trying to serialize the value to be written to the application data store
>   If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: You should be able to get inner exception details to check which property `RemoveFavourites` class is not being serialized successfully. Some types, say `SolidColorBrush`, are not serializable.

Comment: Please show the definition of the actual type for `T` which you are using; the problem might be causes by the specific type. Please show also the definition of the list in the configuration file.

Comment: Thankyou nvartak and codor for your quick responses i have updated the question.

Comment: Have you tried using `App.removalList.ToArray()` ?

Comment: Yes i did and it also gave me the same error.

Comment: This is the perfect job for an xml serializer!

Answer (score 4):

You can not store complex objects in app settings. ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx#app_settings))

Try to serialize the object (maybe using json or custom way of serializing you have implemented yourself) and then store the data.

Comment: Are you totally sure that it is impossible or is ist just impossible to configure in the IDE of Visual Studio?

Comment: see the reference @Codor

Comment: Thanks for the hint; note that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688724/how-to-store-a-list-of-objects-in-application-settings) suggests using custom formatting to store objects of user-defined types (which could be considered as 
'shoe-horning' one mechanism into another).