# List<myClass> not saving in settings.settings

Tags: c#, settings.settings

I'm trying to save a `List<T>` into the settingsfile of my project.

I've edited the settings.settings file and added

```
<Setting Name="CustomTabs" Type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;CustomTabItem&gt;" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
</Setting>
```

and edited the settings.designer.cs too

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
public global::System.Collections.Generic.List<CustomTabItem> CustomTabs {
    get {
        return ((global::System.Collections.Generic.List<CustomTabItem>)(this["CustomTabs"]));
    }
    set {
        this["CustomTabs"] = value;
    }
}
```

So the Listtype is available in the settings-gui.

Now if I make `Properties.Settings.Default.CustomTabs.Add(tab);` The list gets filled, however if I call `Save();` and restart the App, the list ist empty again.

Am I missing something to make it work? I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: The Save() method only saves anything when it knows that a setting has changed.  It doesn't know that you called Add(), that did not modify the property.  It only modified the list.  You'll have to reassign CustomTabs to make it smarter.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You don't have to change the settings.settings file</s>

Try removing the setting

```
<Setting Name="CustomTabs" Type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;CustomTabItem&gt;" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
</Setting>
```

from the settings.settings file

Also, remember to read back the stored "CustomTabs" settings value during application startup.

EDIT:2
No harm even if settings.settings file is changed like below:

```
<Setting Name="myTestDataList" Type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;TestData&gt;" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
    </Setting>
```

The sample application is still able to retrieve the previous data during next application start up.

EDIT:
I made a sample application:

Added below setting manually in settings.Designer.cs

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
        public System.Collections.Generic.List<TestData> myTestDataList
        {
            get
            {
                return ((System.Collections.Generic.List<TestData>)(this["myTestDataList"]));
            }
            set
            {
                this["myTestDataList"] = value;
            }
        }
```

My data class

```
public class TestData
    {
        public string A {get; set;}
        public string B { get; set; }
    }
```

button-1: stores the data

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<TestData> myList = new List<TestData>();
            myList.Add(new TestData() { A = "Str1", B = "Str2" });
            myList.Add(new TestData() { A = "Str3", B = "Str4" });

            Properties.Settings.Default["myTestDataList"] = myList;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

button-2: retrieves the data even during next application run

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<TestData> myList = Properties.Settings.Default["myTestDataList"] as List<TestData>;
}
```

Comment: I had to edit it manually because the Gui wont get access to List if you dont do it. I try to restore it, but its empty as i said. Btw all the simple types e.g. string get saved

Comment: well, you have manually edited both settings.settings file and settings.designer.cs file. Can you throw away your edit on settings.settings file but still keep your edit on settings.designer.cs file and give it a try ?

Comment: Makes no difference.

Comment: @Nitro.de I added some sample code that works for me. sorry if it couldn't help you further

Comment: Well i tried your snipped and it works, maybe the class i try to insert into the list is just to huge or complex.

Comment: ah! may be your custom class should handle serialization ? please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688724/how-to-store-a-list-of-objects-in-application-settings