# how saving List<object> to settings in C# uwp

Tags: c#, save, win-universal-app, settings, listobject

how I can saving List to settings in C# uwp?

define class for object

```
//class    

public class ListOfFile
        {
            public string File_DisplayName { get; set; }
            public string File_Name { get; set; }
            public string File_path { get; set; }
            public string File_Extension { get; set; }
            public StorageFile File_Storage { get; set; }
            public ImageSource File_Thumbnail { get; set; }
        }
```

define method For loadfile
Method:

```
//method
void loadfile()
{
    List<ListOfFile> FileBind=new List<ListOfFile>();
     var FilesInFolder = await FolderItem.GetFilesAsync();

    foreach(var FileItem in FilesInFolder)
    {
           FileBind.Add(new ListOfFile()
                        {
                            File_DisplayName = FileItem.DisplayName,
                            File_Extension = FileItem.FileType
                        ,
                            File_Name = FileItem.Name
                        ,
                            File_path = FileItem.Path
                        ,
                            File_Thumbnail = bitmapimage
                        ,
                            File_Storage =FileItem
                        });
    }

    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["allfiles"]=FileBind;
}
```

end line Error :(

how I can saveing list in Settings?
help me please.

Answer (score 6):

## UWP Community Toolkit - Object Storage

I know this is over half a year since the original question was asked, but I wish I had found out about the UWP toolkit sooner, as I had a similar situation where I wanted to quickly and easily store a simple class list of device information to roam in roaming settings. Posting this here in case it might be use to someone else in a similar situation like the OP and myself.

If your application targets Windows 10 Build 10586 or higher, you can use the Object Storage helpers that are part of the [UWP Community Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit) by Microsoft to store small or large objects, which also includes Lists.

You can add the toolkit by adding the **Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp** NuGet package to your UWP project.

### Example for LocalObjectStorageHelper ([Snippet Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/dev/docs/helpers/ObjectStorage.md))

```
var helper = new LocalObjectStorageHelper();

// Read simple objects
string keySimpleObject = "simple";
if (helper.KeyExists(keySimpleObject))
{
    string result = helper.Read<string>(keySimpleObject);
}

// Save simple objects
helper.Save(keySimpleObject, 47);

// Read complex/large objects 
string keyLargeObject = "large";
if (await helper.FileExistsAsync(keyLargeObject))
{
    var result = await helper.ReadFileAsync<MyLargeObject>(keyLargeObject);
}

// Save complex/large objects 
var o = new MyLargeObject
{
    ...
};
await helper.SaveFileAsync(keySimpleObject, o);
```

Same can be done with **RoamingObjectStorageHelper**.

### Important Notes

You can save both simple and complex objects like lists using **Save(key, object)** and **SaveFileAsync(key, object)**.

**Save** will store the object in local/roaming settings (depending on the storage helper you pick); This means it is subject to data constraints and the total serialized object size must be less than 8 KB.

**SaveFileAsync** will store the object as a serialized file in the *LocalState* or *RoamingState* directories of your app (at least, I believe so) to be accessed later using ReadFileAsync. Use this if your object is very complex and you expect might serialize into a size greater than 8 KB.

#### Important Caveat

Be careful when storing large/complex objects or list of objects using **SaveFileAsync**. Each UWP app is only allotted 100 KB (AKA the [**RoamingStorageQuota**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241625)). If the quota is exceeded, data replication will cease.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that [ApplicationData.LocalSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) has limitations.

Each setting can be up to 8K bytes in size.

You are trying to store

```
List<T>
```

in settings.
Take a look at supported [types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205768.aspx)

```
List<T>
```

is missing there. Looks like you can't do it this way. There is might be only with some converting to object

Take a look at solution on this similar topic:
[How to store a list of objects in application settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688724/how-to-store-a-list-of-objects-in-application-settings)

UPDATE:

You can try replace BinaryFormatter with DataContractSerializer.
Here is nice article that might help you: [Saving and Loading App Data (Windows Store C# UWP / 8.1)](http://matthiasshapiro.com/2015/12/10/saving-and-loading-app-data-windows-store-c-uwp-8-1/)

Comment: you can try DataContractSerializer. I have add another link to my answer that might help you

Comment: Thanks is ok . Now problem  saving storagefile with serializer 

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing entire files and bitmap images to settings. That is not the correct use of an app's settings feature. At the most, you can store a list of files and their paths, which may allow you to read the contents and display a thumbnail at run-time. If you had mentioned exactly what it is you're trying to achieve, then maybe we could help you a little better.

If you absolutely need to store entire files within your app, you can either [copy those files into your app's local storage folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files) or you can look into [integrating with OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-determining-availability-of-microsoft-onedrive-files) for a more portable solution.