# Encrypting XML custom configuration file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, encryption, configuration-files

I have this method which populates an object from my XML "custom configuration" config file:

```
public static BindingList<StationConfiguration> GetStationsFromConfigFile()
{
    string xmlDocumentText = File.ReadAllText(GetConfigFilePath());
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xmlDocumentText);

    BindingList<StationConfiguration> stations = new BindingList<StationConfiguration>();
    foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement["StationsSection"].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes)
    {
        stations.Add(
            new StationConfiguration(
                node.Attributes["Comment"].Value
                , node.Attributes["FtpUsername"].Value
                , node.Attributes["FtpPassword"].Value
                , node.Attributes["DestinationFolderPath"].Value
            ));
    }

    return stations;
}
```

As you can see, I'm using `File.ReadAllText` to pull the contents of the XML config file into a String.

This all works well for a non-encrypted config file. But now I need to encrypt it. The way [MSDN suggests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) doing that begins like this:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config =
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
    ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

(Incidentally, when I look at the `config.FilePath` property, it shows me the correct path of the XML config file, just having an extra ".config" extension for some strange reason. It ends with ".exe.config.**config**" for some odd reason. *But I digress...*)

This is my `StationConfigurationSection` class:

```
public class StationConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Stations", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(StationCollection),
        AddItemName = "add",
        ClearItemsName = "clear",
        RemoveItemName = "remove")]
    public StationCollection Stations
    {
        get
        {
            return (StationCollection)base["Stations"];
        }
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My complete XML config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="StationsSection" type="EcFtpClient.StationConfigurationSection, EcFtpClient" />
  </configSections>
  <StationsSection>
    <Stations>
      <add Comment="ABC" FtpUsername="eliezer" FtpPassword="secret" DestinationFolderPath="C:\Users\eliezer\Desktop\local dest" FtpTimeoutInSeconds="30" FtpHostname="ftp://192.168.1.100/" FtpFolderPath="" />
    </Stations>
  </StationsSection>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="NameOfService" value="ECClient" />
    <add key="PollingFrequencyInSeconds" value="60" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I would like to use the MSDN `System.Configuration` approach, since it makes en/de-cryption very easy, but how can I blend their approach with what I have to make it work?

**-- UPDATE --**
I've got the *loading* of the file but am still stuck when it comes to *saving* the file.
I've changed the loading method (at the very top of this question) to this:

```
public static BindingList<StationConfiguration> GetStationsFromConfigFile()
{
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(GetConfigFilePath());
    StationConfigurationSection stationsConfig = (StationConfigurationSection)config.GetSection("StationsSection");
    var stationCollection = ((StationCollection)stationsConfig.Stations);

    BindingList<StationConfiguration> stationsToReturn = new BindingList<StationConfiguration>();

    for (int index = 0; index < stationCollection.Count; index++)
    {
        stationsToReturn.Add(
            new StationConfiguration(
                stationCollection[index].Comment,
                stationCollection[index].FtpUsername,
                stationCollection[index].FtpPassword,
                stationCollection[index].DestinationFolderPath)
            );

    return stationsToReturn;
}
```

What that gets me is the ability to load a file regardless of whether it's encrypted or not - it loads successfully. That's great.

But I'm still not sure how to get saving working. Here's my save method:

```
public static void SaveStationsToConfigFile(BindingList<StationConfiguration> updatedStations, bool isConfigToBeEncrypted)
{
    string configFilePath = GetConfigFilePath();

    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(configFilePath);
    var xDeclaration = xDoc.Declaration;
    var xElement = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//StationsSection/Stations");

    // clear out existing station configurations
    xDoc.Descendants("Stations").Nodes().Remove();

    foreach (var station in updatedStations)
    {
        xElement.Add(new XElement("add",
                new XAttribute("Comment", station.Station),
                new XAttribute("FtpUsername", station.Username),
                new XAttribute("FtpPassword", station.Password),
                new XAttribute("DestinationFolderPath", station.FolderName),
                new XAttribute("FtpTimeoutInSeconds", 30),
                new XAttribute("FtpHostname", GetEnvironmentAppropriateFtpHostName()),
                new XAttribute("FtpFolderPath", GetEnvironmentAppropriateFtpFolderPath())
        ));
    }

    xDoc.Declaration = xDeclaration;
    xDoc.Save(configFilePath);
}
```

And in order to save it with the protection/encrpytion, I need to do something like this - in other words, using the `System.Configuration.Configuration` objects:

```
stationsConfig.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");
stationsConfig.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
objConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

But I'm currently still doing the save with `XDocument.Save`...

**Is there a way to convert my XDocument into a `System.Configuration.Configuration` compatible object?**
*The hack that comes to mind is after the call to `XDocument.Save` - to load it and save it again using the `System.Configuration.Configuration` stuff. But that's a hack...*

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to play along with the [configuration settings framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8627974/12597). Rather than trying to open the xml file yourself, you need to create a descendant of **ConfigurationSection**.

That way it will read and write from the encrypted configuration for you.

It looks like you already started that route (`EcFtpClient.StationConfigurationSection`), but you didn't include any of that code.

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the code of `EcFtpClient.StationConfigurationSection`. It already *does* inherit from `ConfigurationSection`... Is that what you meant?

Comment: I'm thinking this [ProtectedConfigurationSection Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.protectedconfigurationsection(v=vs.90).aspx) is likely the best thing to use. I **thought** this would help: [Implementing Protected Configuration With Windows Apps](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15392/Implementing-Protected-Configuration-With-Windows) - but I just can't figure out how to integrate it with what I've curretly got...